# How to modify a field of a field of a .... As in link.next.next.next(.next*n) n times

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have an array which holds links. Each link has a public field called next which can hold another link, which can hold any more links ect. When I want to delete things I can do

```
    array[x].next = array[x].next.next;
```

which would delete the 2nd item. But I want to be able to delete any item, so how can I get it into a form with variables? The equation would be something along these lines: If I wanna delete item n I would do

```
    array[x](.next*(n-1)) = array[x](.next*n);
```

Which for n = 4 would exand to

```
    array[x].next.next.next = array[x].next.next.next.next;
```

Hopefully my question is clear. I need to know how to do it this way as I cannot set a getter or any other code into my link class, and since Im the sole owner of my code I am not going to incorectly set my the field. Java.

Answer (score 3):

So let's say we have `array[x].next.next.next.next`.  The compiler accepts this and tells the runtime how to get to our fourth element.  How does it do this?  Well...

```
Entry current = array[x];
current = current.next;
current = current.next;
current = current.next;
current = current.next;
```

If we translate this into a for-loop, we get the following:

```
Entry current = array[x];
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    current = current.next;
}
```

In fact, that looks a lot like the way [`java.util.LinkedList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.entry%28int%29) does it:

```
/**
 * Returns the indexed entry.
 */
private Entry<E> entry(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index+
                                            ", Size: "+size);
    Entry<E> e = header;
    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        //  vvv  Looks familiar?
        for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
            e = e.next;
        //  ^^^
    } else {
        for (int i = size; i > index; i--)
            e = e.previous;
    }
    return e;
}
```